# Per section figure numbering - reset counter each section

Tags: graphics, floats, numbering

I would like to achieve book like figure numbering for my article class document. MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% optionally - this creates: Figure 1.1 ... Figure 2.2
%\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{figure}}

\begin{document}

\section{first section}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
    \caption{figure 1.1} % should be 1.1
\end{figure}

\section{second section}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1.png}
    \caption{figure 2.1} % should be 2.1 - actually is 2 or 2.2 with optional code
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I do not want to reset the counter manually on each section.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is easily achieved using `\numberwithin` from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{first section}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \rule{4cm}{4cm}  % replace with image
    \caption{figure 1.1} 
\end{figure}

\section{second section}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
    \rule{4cm}{4cm}  % replace with image
    \caption{figure 2.1} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: captions]

Comment: One could also use the `chngcntr` package; it defines a `\counterwithin` command, that does the same as `\numberwithin` and a `\counterwithin*` command that doesn't prefix the figure number with the section number/. Il also defines `\counterwithout` and `\counterwithout*` commands, that do the reverse.

Comment: I am seeing a lot of solutions for implementing section wise figure numbers but none for continuous numbering through sections. I never had this problem before.  Something must have changed in the MacTeX distribution which made section wise numbering a default.

Comment: @cryptic0 --- As far as I know, the default in the standard document classes is continuous numbering in article and per chapter in report and book. It's unlikely that this has changed in in the last quarter century or so. It's not difficult to adjust the behaviour in either direction, but how you do it may depend on the document class. I suggest posting a new question if you need help with this.