# How to number listings by section number?

Tags: listings, numbering

I want to include several listings in my document with sections. I also want each listing to have labels like **Listing 2.1** where 2 is section number and 1 is number of given listing within that section. So far I was able to produce this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=Trbl,numbers=left}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}

\section{Introduction}
First listing is numbered properly.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=First listing]
Lorem
Ipsum
\end{lstlisting}
Second is correct too.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Second listing]
Dolor sit Amet
\end{lstlisting}
So far, all listings in one section are correct.
\section{First problem}
When a new section begins, the counter doesn't get reset.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=First listing in second section]
consectetur
adispicing
elit
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But this produces the following result:
[image: Produced result]

How can I reset the counter after the beginning of each section?

Comment: This TEX.SE should solve this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203790/per-section-figure-numbering-reset-counter-each-section

Comment: `\numberwithin{lstlisting}{section}` produces error `No counter 'lstlisting' defined. \numberwithin{lstlisting}{section}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution is to include package `chngcntr` and to place `\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}` after `\begin{document}`. The complete code is then

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings,chngcntr}
\lstset{frame=Trbl,numbers=left}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}

\section{Introduction}
First listing is numbered properly.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=First listing]
Lorem
Ipsum
\end{lstlisting}
Second is correct too.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Second listing]
Dolor sit Amet
\end{lstlisting}
So far, all listings in one section are correct.
\section{First problem}
When a new section begins, the counter doesn't get reset.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=First listing in second section]
consectetur
adispicing
elit
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

which produces the desired output:
[image: Correct output]

Comment: I am gettng this `Package chngcntr Error: lstlisting is not a counter \counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}`

Comment: @jonaprieto Strange, my MWE compiles on my computer. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and LaTeX Studio 2.12.0 . Did you `\usepackage{listings}`?

Comment: yes; I was my mistake, I put it before begin document. sorry.