# lstlisting label with wrong counting across sections

Tags: listings

All my listings labels appear with prefix 1. in all sections, such as the following example, where the second listing of my paper in section 2 appears with the prefix 1. rather than 2.

I have already realized that `\maketitle` is the root of this behavior. If I remove `\maketitle` the labels appear correctly with 1 and 2, rather than 1.1 and 1.2.

How can we keep consistent numbering with the following llncs template:

```latex
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\title{PetClinic Sample}

\maketitle

\section{Intro}
\label{sec:alternatives}

We will use the PetClinic Spring~\ref{lst:input}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={HTML}, caption={Button}, label={lst:button} ]    
<button></button>
\end{lstlisting}

\section{Idioms}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={HTML},caption={Input},label={lst:input}]    
<input>
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Make a complete example. That makes it much easier to test the issue.

Comment: Done. I have included a complete example. Thanks

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238840/how-to-number-listings-by-section-number

Comment: From the proposed duplicates: `\usepackage{chngcntr}\begin{document}\counterwithout{lstlisting}{section}` will number listings continuously and not per section. However, Springer may not like it if you do that, so if you are planning to submit this somewhere then it may be changed back upon publication.

Comment: This one answers https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238840/how-to-number-listings-by-section-number. Yet the solution bellow is better because it does not require auxiliary packages

Answer (score 1):

As your class sets up a chapter counter listings uses it. You can switch to section like this:

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{listings}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}%
             \renewcommand\thelstlisting{\thesection.\arabic{lstlisting}}}

\begin{document}

\title{PetClinic Sample}

\maketitle

\section{Intro}
\label{sec:alternatives}

We will use the PetClinic Spring~\ref{lst:input}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={HTML}, caption={Button}, label={lst:button} ]
<button></button>
\end{lstlisting}

\section{Idioms}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={HTML},caption={Input},label={lst:input}]
<input>
\end{lstlisting}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Following your suggestion the second listing appears with 2.2. It should be 2.1

Comment: @FernandoMiguelCarvalho thanks, I edited the answer.