# Creating a custom image counter

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, counters

Good day to everyone!

I should like to apologize in advance for this sort of question -- however, I am extremely pressed for time and am unable to do my own research and experimentation.

I am new to LaTeX, but I have decided to write my seminal paper using it because I am positively sick and tired of various office solutions.

I need to create a figure counter for `\documentclass{article}` that would work like this:

```
Figure [chapternum].[imagenuminchapter]: [caption]
```

So for example, the second figure in the 3rd chapter would have the caption:

```
Figure 3.2: Some caption
```

The first image in the 4th chapter would be:

```
Figure 4.1: Some other caption
```

And so on.

Thank you all in advance, and again, I am terribly sorry for this "please write it for me" sort of question, I do hope you will understand.

Comment: I only see the [] as a difference of most templates with chapter default behavior And I suppose you don't even want it. For example in a book you don't need to have a new counter or something for this. Figure's numbers are already like this. You have to give us at least the documentclass to check it.

Comment: @koleygr apologies, I'm writing the document with the `article` class. I updated my question.

Comment: The `article` class does not have chapters. Perhaps you mean you want to enumerate the figures with the section numbers, `[sectnum].[imagenum]`? If so, you can look at [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203791/117534), for example. If you want chapters, then a documentclass like `report` might suit you better.

Comment: @Troy yes, absolutely! That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!